# Why won't my JSON array query work?

Tags: php, mysql, json

Can anyone see what the problem with my code is / where im going wrong?

I know i have the correct host,database,user and password.

This is the code in the php file, it should get all the details available on the players from my sql database, however if i go on the page it just gives me a white page. Im using go daddy as a host and my database is also on there.

Any ideas? thanks

```
<?php

$host = "abc12345"; //Your database host server
$db = "abc12345"; //Your database name
$user = "abc12345"; //Your database user
$pass = "abc12345"; //Your password

$connection = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass);

//Check to see if we can connect to the server
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database server connection failed.");
} else {
    //Attempt to select the database
    $dbconnect = mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

    //Check to see if we could select the database
    if (!$dbconnect) {
        die("Unable to connect to the specified database!");
    } else {

        $query = "SELECT * FROM Player";
        $resultset = mysql_query($query);

        $records = array();

        //Loop through all our records and add them to our array
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultset)) {
            $records[] = $r;
        }

        //Output the data as JSON
        echo json_encode($records);
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you sure `SELECT * FROM Player` is working? Maybe table is called `Players`? It this query working in your db manager? Try to output something after `echo json_encode($records);` Will it be outputted?

Comment: It's 100% 'Player', I've connected to the database many times and populated tables etc.. this time i've tried using json because I'm also creating an ios application thats using the json array to populate a table..... but i can't see why nothing appears on my php page

Comment: Did you tried to output something in this branch of `if`? Something like `echo 'bob';` Do you see `bob` on your page then?

Comment: not yet as im quite new to all this, and also needing to complete other work. But thanks to everyone for their suggestions and if you have new ones please comment. When i resolve this issue i will post how i done it

Comment: @steff I've mentioned a couple of things to look for in my answer, let me know if they help.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what has happened but it seems to be working now, all i done was make it from scratch again. Thanks for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script is all right, I checked it with a different query.

Assuming that the table `Player` is not empty, the error can be either with your raw sql query (as pointed by @Sharikov in comments), otherwise the error is with the way you have configured your godaddy server.

For debugging that, I would suggest inserting dummy `print_r` or `echo` statements before you execute the query, and going through your `apache` logs at `/var/log/apache2/access.log`.

Also make sure that you don't have any core `php` package missing on your server (like `php5-mysql` if you use `mysql`).